# Video lag on youtube / internet streams for all browsers

Tags: video, youtube

The audio is fine just the video lags. With youtube some videos are fine and others unwatchable. The upgrade to 16.04 didn't change anything. 
I'm using firefox but tried chrome and had the same issues. I've had this problem since forever and really need help.
I'm pretty sure though it wasn't like this from the beginning.

Thank you so much!